# why javascript prototypal inheritance works different for methods and properties of class?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am learning Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript. I have encountered this weird thing while calling methods and variables of child class object whose prototype is parent class object. Refer to the code below.

```js
class childX {
    vehicleType = "Not Available";
    methX(){
        console.log("Hello from the ChildX object");
    }
}

class ParentX {
    vehicleType = "Truck";
    methX(){
        console.log("Hello from the ParentX object");
    }
}

let childObj = new childX();
let parentObj = new ParentX();

childObj.__proto__ = parentObj;
console.log("Child Vehicle Type: ", childObj.vehicleType);// output: Not Available
childObj.methX(); // output: Hello from the ParentX object
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto - lists this as depreciated. What exactly would you like to accomplish? MDN claims that you can use this instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf setPrototypeOf()

Comment: The correct way to do inheritance is via the [`extends`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) keyword, not by manually setting the prototype. Other than that, `vehicleType = "Not Available";` creates a field, i.e. a property on the instance itself, whereas `methX` is a method which is a property on the prototype of the instance. All instances of a specific class share the same prototype, so these methods only get created once. Since fields are usually for primitives, it makes sense for each instance to get its own property. Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) keyword

```js
class ParentX {
  vehicleType = "Truck";
  methX() {
    console.log("Hello from the ParentX object");
  }
}


class childX extends ParentX {
  vehicleType = "Not Available";
  methX() {
    console.log("Hello from the ChildX object");
  }
  x() {
    console.log('x still works')
  }
}


let childObj = new childX();
let parentObj = new ParentX();

console.log("Child Vehicle Type: ", childObj.vehicleType);
childObj.methX();
childObj.x();
```

But if you really don't want to do this use `Object.setPrototypeOf` as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#extending_plain_objects)

```js
class childX {
  vehicleType = "Not Available";
  methX() {
    console.log("Hello from the ChildX object");
  }
  x() {
    console.log('x still works')
  }
}

class ParentX {
  vehicleType = "Truck";
  methX() {
    console.log("Hello from the ParentX object");
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(childX.prototype, ParentX);

let childObj = new childX();
let parentObj = new ParentX();

console.log("Child Vehicle Type: ", childObj.vehicleType);
childObj.methX();
childObj.x();
```